# What is the relation (if any) of Fanny Buitrago to her biographer Letty Buitrago?

Tags: spanish-language, biography, fanny-buitrago

In the ninth volume ("Biografias") of the Colombian encyclopedia "Gran Enciclopedia de Colombia" there is a biography of the Colombian author Fanny Buitrago. [It can be read here](https://archive.org/details/GranEnciclopediaDeColombiaTomo9BiografiasICirculoDeLectores1993/page/n96) (pages 96-7, in Spanish). It is attributed to Letty Buitrago, so someone of the same surname.

I'd like to know whether Letty is a relative - maybe even a sibling - of Fanny.

The evidence for this, other than the shared name, is the fact that the biography contains quite a lot of specific, unsourced info that only a family member would know, like the birth-places of F.B.'s parents. (This example is particularly noteworthy because [a shorter biography of F.B.](https://archive.org/details/GranEnciclopediaDeColombiaTomo4LiteraturaCirculoDeLectores1992/page/n291) in "Gran Enciclopedia de Colombia 4 Literatura" is more vague about the birthplace of her parents, and was apparently written by someone else).

However I can't find any other evidence, and a shared name is too little to go off, especially because [Buitrago is not an uncommon name in Bogotá](https://forebears.io/surnames/buitrago). I know that F.B. has siblings (and aunts, and a cousin), because she says so in [a 1990 article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211127225907/https://colombianistas.org/wp-content/themes/pleasant/REC/REC%209/El%20oficio%20del%20escritor/2.REC_9_FannyBuitrago.pdf). I'm having a hard time finding more info because my Spanish is not very good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, sisters.

From a [2016 piece by Nadia Celis](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f4c6/e68f4d56e61a35ea663221785316837e7819.pdf):

> Ese tercer ojo, curioso, precoz, inquisitivo y certero, marcó desde muy temprano el destino de Fanny Buitrago. **Letty Buitrago, hermana, editora y agente de la autora**,  recuerda como “desde muy pequeña, Fanny miraba a la gente en silencio, con ojos curiosos, estudiando su manera de proceder y se creía que a veces juzgando y censurando sus actos, pero en realidad era con ojo observador”.
>
> ---
>
> "That third eye—curious, precocious, inquisitive, accurate—betrayed Fanny Buitrago's nature from a very early age. **Letty Buitrago, sister, editor, and agent of the author**, remembers how,“from a very young age, Fanny looked at people in silent, curious appraisal, studying their ways and manners. Some thought she was judging, no, she was simply observing."

Some of the stories in *La Casa del Verde Doncel* are also dedicated to Letty and their brother Luis.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! I couldn't follow your link so I found the article and edited the link.

Comment: @user1118 - thanks, sorry it didn't work the first time. Glad this helped!